# keep everything upto last column but remove character before last space in last column

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How can I remove all characters in last column upto last space?

```
20160101|193.150.22.1|57381|0.0.0.0/0|57381 42708 29468 41136 41136 41136 3292
```

The result should be as below:

```
20160101|193.150.22.1|57381|0.0.0.0/0|3292
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this for instance with `sed`:

```
echo "20160101|193.150.22.1|57381|0.0.0.0/0|57381 42708 29468 41136 41136 41136 3292" | sed -e 's/\(|.*|\).* \(.*\)/\1\2/'
```

gives:

```
20160101|193.150.22.1|57381|0.0.0.0/0|3292
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to get the result with only `bash`-internal functionality, you can use `bash` [substring removal](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

```
s="20160101|193.150.22.1|57381|0.0.0.0/0|57381 42708 29468 41136 41136 41136 3292"
echo "${s%|*}|${s##* }"
```

also gives the desired result.